# $p(x)$ is divisible by $(ax+b)^n$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

> Show that if the polynomial $p(x)$ is divisible by $(ax+b)^n$, then $p'(x)$ is divisible by $(ax + b)^{n-1}$ where $n > 1$

A polynomial $f(x)$ to be divisible by another polynomial $g(x)$, there should be another polynomial $s(x)$, such that $f(x) = g(x)s(x)$

Now my $p(x) = (ax+b)^n s(x)$

Then my $p'(x) = ((ax+b)^n)' s(x) + ((ax+b)^n) (s(x))'$

$p'(x) = n(ax+b)^{n-1}(ax + b)' s(x) + ((ax+b)^n) (s(x))$

$p'(x) = n(ax+b)^{n-1} (a + b) s(x) + ((ax+b)^n) (s(x))$

but I do not know how to proceed anymore? Can anybody give me a hint? 
And about the $s(x)$, should I leave the $s(x)$ just like this or I have to give an expression (value) to it?

Comment: Literally just factorize.

Comment: Also, $(ax+b)' = a \neq a+b$ for _some_ $b$.

Comment: I'm almost new in Stack Exchange, but the two guys that answered are correct, how am I supposed to decide which one to give the "Correct Answer" !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some slips:
\begin{align}
p'(x)
&=\bigl((ax+b)^ns(x)\bigr)'\\
&=\bigl((ax+b)^n\bigr)'s(x)+(ax+b)^ns'(x)\\
&=n(ax+b)^{n-1}(ax+b)'s(x)+(ax+b)^ns'(x)\\
&=n(ax+b)^{n-1}as(x)+(ax+b)^ns'(x)
\end{align}
You forgot some prime and that $(ax+b)'=a$ and not $a+b$. Now collect $(ax+b)^{n-1}$ getting
$$
p(x)=(ax+b)^{n-1}\bigl(nas(x)+(ax+b)s'(x)\bigr)
$$
and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}p'(x) &= n\color{blue}{(ax+b)^{n-1}} \color{red}a  s(x) + \color{blue}{((ax+b)^n)} \color{red}{(s'(x))} \\
&= \color{blue}{(ax+b)^{n-1}} \left(\color{red}ans(x)+\color{blue}{(ax+b)}\color{red}{s'(x)}\right)\end{align}